# "How to burn a DVD on OS X" but DVD does not boot

Tags: boot, dvd, burning

I followed all the steps about hot to burn a DVD on OS X as in http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/burn-a-dvd-on-mac-osx

but..
(after using the file ubuntu-14.04.3-desktop-amd64.iso )

even that I got "burned" (steps 1-6) properly and the disk was ejected( "normal ending"),  I tried to use the dvd (DVD+R 4.7 GB ).. but it does not work.

Indeed, I did shut down the Mac, and I restarted holding "C" key after turning on my computer.
What may be my mistake?

I tried to "see" the dvd, but I see the message " The disk you inserted was not readable by this computer.".

Thanks in advance for any comment and help.
JJ

Comment: This is probably better asked on http://apple.stackexchange.com/ You are asking about a system we know 'nothing' about so you need someone to tell you how to analyze the disk from inside OS X. It could be a problem with the software you use on OS X.

Comment: What model of Mac are you using?

Comment: Have you verified the [hash value](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuHashes) of your download yet? (Could be a bad download), otherwise, head over to [apple.se] where they will be able to help you better as they know more about fruity stuff then most of us know...

Comment: Thank you. Apparently it s problem of my MacBook Pro9.1 (running on OS x Yosemite 10.10.5). Why? The same dvd burned with my MacBook Pro9.1 I used in a MacBook Pro8.1 (with Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5) and ..IT WORKS. I will need to ask in apple.stackexchange.com.. Thank you very much for all the help and comments!!. Jean-Jacques

Comment: Did you ask this on http://apple.stackexchange.com/ ? Which is the link to the question?